# Nested OR function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide rows if any of the 'And' conditions are not met, but it's only working for Range "C11" and not for the entire range. please help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("C10").Value = "Pass" And
       Range("C11").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C12").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C13").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C14").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C15").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C16").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C17").Value = "Pass" And 
       Range("C18").Value = "Pass" Then
        Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("C10").Value = "Pass" Then
         Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("C11").Value = "Fail" Then
        Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("C11").Value = "Pass" Then
         Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So to clarify, if all cells in the range `C10:C18` are `Pass` then you should hide rows 19-47, otherwise they should be shown?

Comment: you need to switch the True/False in the first if.  your logic is backwards

Comment: No, actually I want to keep the rows hidden till all of them are "Pass".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WorksheetFunction.Countif` to count if there are any entries which are not "Pass". See below code

```
  If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("C10:C18"), "<>Pass")=0 Then
      Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = True
  ElseIf Range("C10").Value = "Pass" Then
       Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = False
  End If
```

You can also use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("C10:C18"), "Pass")<>9`

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your data? That will be helpful to understand why is this not working. I have actually tried this out with a sample data of my own.

Comment: I have figured it out  ----------Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("C10:C18"), "Pass") <> 9 Then
      Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = True
  Else: Range(Rows(19), Rows(47)).Hidden = False
  End If
ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"
End Sub